# Function which takes an integer k that checks if a list of integer lists l, returns the count of the number of integer lists in l, which sum to k

Tags: python, list, loops

For example: `sumToK(10,[[1,2],[1,2,3,4],[5,5,0],[8,2,3],[-15,25]])` returns `3` since 3 of the inner 5 lists in the given list sum exactly to 10. I can use the sum function, and other functions such as max, min, len. I need to do this with code using a while loop and code using a for loop.

So far I have this for the for loop but lost on the while loop:

```
def sumTotal(k, l):
    count = 0
    for x in l:
       count += x
    return count
```

The problem for me is checking for multiple lists and counting how many add up to k

Comment: you forgot to add your code. `sum(sum(i) == 10 for i in [[1,2],[1,2,3,4],[5,5,0],[8,2,3],[-15,25]])`

Comment: I like the recursive version better.

Comment: I also need to do this recursively, which I'm stuck on as well

Comment: @OlvinRoght This did work thank you, but is there also a while loop version similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version with while loop as you asked in the post

Modifies initial list:

```
def sumTotal(k, l):
  ans = 0
  while l:
    curr = l.pop()
    if sum(curr) == k:
      ans += 1
  return ans


ans = sumTotal(10, [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 5, 0], [8, 2, 3], [-15, 25]])
print(ans) # outputs 3
```

Does not modify initial list:

```
def sumTotal(k, l):
  ans = 0
  idx = 0
  while idx < len(l):
    if sum(l[idx]) == k:
      ans += 1
    idx += 1
  return ans


ans = sumTotal(10, [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 5, 0], [8, 2, 3], [-15, 25]])
print(ans) # outputs 3
```

**Update**

I added a recursion solution but honestly it's not the type of the task, which you want to solve recursively. Recursion takes O(n) space, which is unnecessary there.

```
def sumTotal(k, l, index = 0):
  if index == len(l):
    return 0
  else:
    return sumTotal(k, l, index + 1) + (1 if sum(l[index]) == k else 0)

ans = sumTotal(10, [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 5, 0], [8, 2, 3], [-15, 25]])
print(ans) # outputs 3
```

Comment: One more way is to use an iterator with `next()` ;-)

Comment: @OlvinRoght I guess there is a million different ways of how to solve this task :)

Comment: I know this is kinda off topic of what I asked but I also need to do this recursively and I'm stuck, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @HUNTERFRASER I updated the post and added a recursive solution

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped a lot.